# log in non sidekiq class

Tags: ruby, heroku, sidekiq

I have a worker that delegates the work to another class like this:

```
class SynJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :sync

  def perform(user_id)
    OtherClass.new(blah, blah, blah)
  end
end

class OtherClass
  def initialize
    puts "we are in OtherClass"
  end
end
```

My question is, how do I log to stdout from OtherClass.

My puts statements do not show up in the heroku stdout log.

Comment: Did you check the `worker` specific log? `heroku log --ps worker`?

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is to use `puts` or other Ruby APIs for writing to stdout.  You can call this both in your `SynJob` or your `OtherClass` code and it will execute the same, writing to the stdout of the sidekiq worker process.

However, this probably is not what you want to do.  If this is a Rails app, you probably want to write to the Rails logger, which should be available both in your worker and in other code:

```
Rails.logger.info "I'm a debug message"
```

This will show up in the appropriate log both locally and when running deployed on Heroku.

Comment: It is a sinatra app. unfortunately.